# Reverse for '' not found '' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, render

I'm getting the above message when trying to view the cart page in my Ecommerce site. I can see that this is a fairly common question but after trawling through multiple other threads here, none of the solutions are working.

In the current iteration of my code I have added an app_name to the cart app and then referenced this in my html, but no joy.

**Traceback:**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/

Django Version: 2.2.5
Python Version: 3.8.1
Installed Applications:
['pages.apps.PagesConfig',
 'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
 'products.apps.ProductsConfig',
 'cart.apps.CartConfig',
 'search.apps.SearchConfig',
 'crispy_forms',
 'storages',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
('whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Template error:
In template C:\Users\Vegeta\OneDrive\Visual Studio Code\milestone-project-four\pages\templates\base.html, error at line 0
   Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
   1 : {% load static %}
   2 : 
   3 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   4 : <html lang="en">
   5 : 
   6 : <head>
   7 :     <meta charset="utf-8" />
   8 :     <!-- Set the viewport to allow responsiveness -->
   9 :     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
   10 :     <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->


Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Vegeta\OneDrive\Visual Studio Code\milestone-project-four\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Vegeta\OneDrive\Visual Studio Code\milestone-project-four\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Vegeta\OneDrive\Visual Studio Code\milestone-project-four\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Vegeta\OneDrive\Visual Studio Code\milestone-project-four\cart\views.py" in view_cart
  7.     return render(request, 'cart.html')

File "C:\Users\Vegeta\OneDrive\Visual Studio Code\milestone-project-four\env\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "C:\Users\Vegeta\OneDrive\Visual Studio Code\milestone-project-four\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "C:\Users\Vegeta\OneDrive\Visual Studio Code\milestone-project-four\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Vegeta\OneDrive\Visual Studio Code\milestone-project-four\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\Vegeta\OneDrive\Visual Studio Code\milestone-project-four\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Vegeta\OneDrive\Visual Studio Code\milestone-project-four\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Vegeta\OneDrive\Visual Studio Code\milestone-project-four\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Vegeta\OneDrive\Visual Studio Code\milestone-project-four\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\Vegeta\OneDrive\Visual Studio Code\milestone-project-four\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Vegeta\OneDrive\Visual Studio Code\milestone-project-four\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Vegeta\OneDrive\Visual Studio Code\milestone-project-four\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Vegeta\OneDrive\Visual Studio Code\milestone-project-four\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  62.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Vegeta\OneDrive\Visual Studio Code\milestone-project-four\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\Vegeta\OneDrive\Visual Studio Code\milestone-project-four\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\Vegeta\OneDrive\Visual Studio Code\milestone-project-four\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  443.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "C:\Users\Vegeta\OneDrive\Visual Studio Code\milestone-project-four\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  90.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\Vegeta\OneDrive\Visual Studio Code\milestone-project-four\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  673.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /cart/
Exception Value: Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

**project urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('products/', include('products.urls')),
    path('cart/', include('cart.urls')),
    path('search/', include('search.urls')),
]
```

**cart app urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import view_cart, add_to_cart

app_name = 'cart'

urlpatterns = [
    path('',  view_cart, name='view_cart'),
    path('add/<slug:pk>', add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart'),
]
```

**cart app views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse
from products.models import Product


def view_cart(request):
    """A View that renders the cart contents page"""
    return render(request, 'cart.html')


def add_to_cart(request, item_id):
    """
    Add an item to the cart
    """
    cart = request.session.get('cart', {})
    if item_id in cart:
        cart[item_id] = int(cart[item_id])
    else:
        cart[item_id] = cart.get(item_id)

    request.session['cart'] = cart
    return redirect(reverse('home'))
```

**base.html nav link to view cart**

```
<li class="nav-item" id="nav-item-cart">
     <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'cart:view_cart' %}"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-1.5x">/i>Cart
         {% if product_count > 0 %}
         <label class="badge badge-warning">{{ product_count }}</label>
         {% endif %}
     </a>
</li>
```

**artifact.html form to add an item to the cart**

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'cart:add_to_cart' artifact.id %}">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <label for="buy" id="buy-header"><strong>Buy lot</strong></label>
     <input name="disabled" type="text" class="input-field" value="£100,000.00" size="8" disabled> 
     <a class="btn btn-sm artifact-btn" type="submit">Add to cart</a>
</form>
```

**cart.html**

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}

    {% block content %}
    <section class="cart-section">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 id="cart-header">Your Cart</h1>

            {% for item in cart_items %}

            <div class="row lot-wrapper">
                <div class="col-5 col-md-6 image-wrapper">
                    <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ item.product.image }}" class="lot-image" alt="Picture of {{ product.name }}">
                </div>
                <div class="col-7 col-md-6 cart-content-wrapper">
                    <h2 class="cart-lot-header">{{ item.name }}</h2>
                    <div class="cart-lot-text">
                        <p><strong>Price</strong> <span class="bid-value"> {{ item.buyout }}</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <p>Grand Total: £{{ total }}</p>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row cart-options">
                <div class="col">
                    <a href="{% url for 'products' %}" class="btn btn-sm" id="continue-btn">Continue shopping</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <a href="checkout.html" class="btn btn-sm" id="checkout-btn">Checkout</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    {% endblock content %}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the problem is in the `cart.html` template - can we see that?

Comment: Updated with cart.html template.

Comment: `{% url for 'products' %}` is wrong syntax - I think you mean `{% url 'products' %}`

Comment: That did it, many thanks. I'll post your comment as the answer and self-accept. Unfortunately I can't mark it as a Community Wiki post as I don't have enough reputation. Alternatively, if you want to put the answer yourself I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is as per Robin Zigmond's comment:

> {% url for 'products' %} is wrong syntax - I think you mean {% url 'products' %}